# How do you make a variable your active cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have used an input box to define a variant as a cell value

```
sub practice()

Dim Value1 as Variant

'Get Input Values
Value1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Click Cell Value", Title:="Specify 
Range", Type:=8)

'Select Variable as the ActiveCell
Value.Select

End Sub
```

The error occurs when I try to select the variable as the activecell. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Replace `Value1 = Application ...` by `Set Value1 = Application ...` (but then why call it a "Value" when you really want a *Range*?) You could make it even clearer by using a `Range` variable rather than a `Variant`.

Comment: Range is probably a better tag. Your code fixes my problem. Thank you!

Comment: You typically don't *want* to `Select` a cell though. Doing that typically implies that you're working off `Selection` and `ActiveCell`, which is what the macro recorder does: such code is extremely frail and bug-prone.

Comment: FWIW - You have a typo as well - `Value.Select` should be `Value1.Select`

Comment: @YowE3K ha, totally missed that! `Option Explicit` FTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range` is an object type. When assigning *object references* in VBA, the `Set` keyword is required.

> ```
> Value1 = ...
> ```

This works, only because `Value1` is declared as a `Variant` (and thus can be literally *anything*) - what's happening is that it's being assigned to whatever *the value* of the selected cell(s) is.

That's because the `Range` class has a *default property* that essentially points to its `Value` member.

This *default property* makes this code:

```
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
```

Equivalent to this code:

```
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
```

So when you assign a `Variant` without the `Set` keyword, you're not assigning an *object reference*, therefore you're assigning a *value*. If the type (`Range`) didn't have a *default member*, the statement would raise a run-time error.

In other words you're looking at a `Variant/String`, or a `Variant/Double`, or a `Variant/Error`, depending on the content of the cell. And you can't invoke `.Select` on any of these!

The solution is therefore to `Set` the `Value1` reference:

```
Set Value1 = ...
```

That way you're assigning to the *object reference*, not to whatever the value of its *default property* is.

Declaring the variable `As Excel.Range` would have made VBA better understand your intent:

```
Dim Value1 As Excel.Range
Value1 = ...
```

This would have raised run-time error 91 "Object reference (or With block variable) not Set", because you can't assign to the default member of an object reference that's set to `Nothing` (which is what an unset object reference will be).

Comment: Awesome! That is super helpful. Does the (Range) Type record the contents of the cell as the range or the cell address?

Comment: @TDoe `Range.Address` gives you the address; `Range.Value` gives you its value, `Range.Value2` gives you more precision when `.Value` is a `Date` or `Currency`. Basically a `Range` represents any cell, or any group of cells.

Comment: oh okay. Functionally then, does that look like

    Dim x as excel.Range.address

Comment: No, `Address` is a member call, you invoke it on an instance of a `Range`, e.g. `MsgBox Value1.Address`. It's a `String` value. You can lookup all the members in the *object browser* (F2).

Comment: ahhh it all makes sense now very cool! thank you so much for the help!